# unable to keep hyperlink to image in salesforce

Tags: visualforce, redirect, images

unable to keep hyperlink to image in salesforce

I am trying to keep hyperlink to image in visualforce

when i click a image it must redirect to url page

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Unless you edit your question and put the code that you have used, people will not be able to help you out on this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use HTML anchor tag with visualforce image tag as body as below:

```
<a href="www.jeganee.com">{!$Resource.JQ}</a>
```